# How to determine if colab ipd.audio player has stopped playing

Tags: javascript, python, audio, google-colaboratory

I am trying to figure out how to tell if an ipd.Audio player on colab has finished playing so that code can execute afterwards. Is there some way to handle it through a javascript event? Thanks.

Comment: Some context on what, specifically, you are trying to do after the player completes may be helpful. I would guess you have to do something in JS in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, use the HTML `Audio` event directly and register an event handler on the `ended` event.

[image]

Here's the full example notebook:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/15FbPqHyY1sgqtLBTJFK8ROgeUMa2syzf?usp=sharing

Comment: Does that still apply if you had an `IPython.lib.display.Audio`? Maybe OP doesn't care about displaying the audio control though...

Comment: You can of course add the HTML element to the DOM again using standard JS APIs, though that feels like a separable question from the one at hand.

Comment: Yes I can generate a play button that calls the audio.play() for the element. Thanks for the help!